# using ruby to checkout a tag in git?

Tags: ruby, git

I want to write a ruby script that is a command line tool that takes a tag ID as a parameter and then runs the equivalent of "git checkout tag_id". I would then use rsync to push the checked out directory to servers. I've looked at the rugged gem and the git gem, but they seem to interact with git in a way that isn't intuitive in doing something like this. Should I just use the system call or is there a more ruby way to do what I'm trying to do?

I have /User/git_repo cloned from say git@github.com/company/this_repo.git. Manually I would "git fetch --tags" and then "git checkout tag_id". I would want to then rsync the result over to the servers.

Comment: If it is a command line tool, then why don't you just use the git command in a non-ruby script?

Comment: I would like to wrap it in a script that would take parameters like the tag id, the git repo, the servers to push to. I also was hoping there would be something in ruby that would give me some handling around what's in the repo and the tags themselves. Not to mention I would like to have handling around the rsync process as well.

Answer (score 3):

There's the [ruby-git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) gem - install it with `$ gem install git`. It handles the system command line calls - here's an example for Ruby >= 1.9:

```
require 'git'

g = Git.init
       Git.init('project')
       Git.init('/home/schacon/proj',
        { :repository => '/opt/git/proj.git',
           :index => '/tmp/index'} )

g.fetch

g.checkout('tag_id')
```

You can get an array of tags from `g.tags`. I'd use this over writing my own system calls, as this repo seems to be currently maintained (last commit [two days ago](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git/commits/master)).